# Can you invert the camera on Sly 2 on the PS Vita?

Tags: ps-vita, sly-2

I can't find a setting to invert the X-axis camera in Sly 2 (PS Vita version). I liked how the camera worked in the first episode (i.e. move right to look left and viceversa) but the default of Sly 2 is the opposite and I hate it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: no, you can't. I have seen some videos on YouTube where this is possible but apparently the settings menu on the PS Vita has been changed and does not allow you to set this option.